# iOS Objective C Webservice

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

Is there any way to keep our web service delegate methods in one class and use them whenever required? Normally I used to keep writing the delegates in all classes such as `didReceiveResponse` and `didReceiveData` etc..;

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do what you want to achieve, but make sure to not overdo it. Too many use of singletons is generally recognized as bad practice.

Make a **Singleton** that you could use throughout your app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html

In your Singleton: *APISingleton*

```
-(void)APIRequestWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary*)params
         onCompletion:(JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock
            onFailure:(OperationFailureBlock)failureBlock{
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[manager GET:kGymEverAPIfullUrl
  parameters:params
     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
         completionBlock(responseObject);
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         failureBlock(operation);
     }];}
```

How to use:

```
-(void)getImages{

NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",1],@"page",@"5",@"count", nil];

[[APISingleton sharedInstance] APIRequestWithParams:params onCompletion:^(id json) {
    postsArray = [json objectForKey:@"posts"];
    [self downloadImages];
} onFailure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation) {
    //Do whatever you want if it does not work.
}];}
```

Using : https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking